# Django: Generate new CSRF token per request/form

Tags: django, csrf

Can we change CSRF token per-form request or even per-request instead of same token for one active session?

Comment: Out of interest: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: to increase the security practice. Event it's hard, attacker still had a chance to steal the csrf token on session-cookie

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the csrf middleware they do something like this, which overwrites the cookie set:

```
request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"] = _get_new_csrf_key()
```

You can import `_get_new_csrf_key()` via `from django.middleware.csrf import _get_new_csrf_key()`. Since is kind of a private method I would advise against some hacks like this though.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to add this to admin page?

Comment: Can you specify what you want to add where exaclty?

Comment: simple, every page request that contain form on admin site need to generate new csrf token. I don't want to rewrite the admin view. I haven;t take a look deep on contrib.admin code, but I believe we can't subclassing in order to do that. So, the only way to do that is to modified contrib.admin directly, is that correct?

Comment: If its going to be one every request you could write a custom middleware to create this token and save it in the session. Just need to find a way to check in the middleware if you are currently using the admin (could be done via url check, etc.).

Answer (score 36):

Assuming that you have access to the **`request`** object:

```
from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token
rotate_token(request)
```

Answer (score 3):

And if you want to use it in a middleware:

```
from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token

class CSRFRefresh(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        rotate_token(request)
        return response
```